# Many to Many Relationships Inserting Null FK records on one of the child tables

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, many-to-many, code-first

I have a model with this structure

1 -TABLEA

2 - MODEL

3 -TABLEB

Definitions:
The Table MODEL has a 1 to many relationship with TABLEA 
The Table MODEL has a 1 to many relationship with TABLEB
TABLEA has a many to many relationship with TABLEB

Each one of these tables have a Model definition of this sort:

```
    With modelBuilder.Entity(Of TABLEA)()
        .Property(Function(t) t.dbTableAID).
            HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasKey(Function(t) t.dbTableAID)
        .Property(Function(t) t.Name).
            HasColumnName("TableName")
        .ToTable("TI")
```

Each type is defined as this:

```
Public Class Model

Public Sub New()
    Me.TableAs = New HashSet(Of TableA)()
    Me.TableBs = New HashSet(Of TableB)()
End Sub

Public Property model_id as integer

Public Overridable Property TableAs() As ICollection(Of TableA)
Public Overridable Property TableBs() As ICollection(Of TableB)

Public Sub LoadModel(Query)

      For Each objTableA In Query.cbsSrcCubes
        Dim objDb As TableA = New TableA()
        Me.TableAs.Add(objDbSrcCube.CastCubeToDB(objDb))
    Next

      For Each objTableB In Query.cbsSrcCubes
        Dim objDb As TableB = New TableB()
        Me.TableBs.Add(objDbSrcCube.CastCubeToDB(objDb))
    Next
End Sub

End Class


Public Class TableA

Public Sub New()
    Me.TableBs = New HashSet(Of TableB)()
End Sub

Public Property TableA_id as integer

Public Overridable Property Model() As Model
Public Overridable Property TableBs() As ICollection(Of TableB)

End Class

Public Class TableB

Public Sub New()
    Me.TableAs = New HashSet(Of TableA)()
End Sub

Public Property TableB_id as integer

Public Overridable Property Model() As Model
Public Overridable Property TableAs() As ICollection(Of TableA)

Public Sub LoadTableA(Query)
      For Each objTableA In Query.TableACol
        Dim objDb As TableA = New TableA()
        Me.TableAs.Add(objDb)
    Next
End Sub


End Class
```

This is the definition of the context

```
Public Class QDModelContext
Inherits DbContext

Public Property Models() As DbSet(Of Model)
Public Property TableAs() As DbSet(Of TableA)
Public Property TableBs() As DbSet(Of TableB)

Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(Of PluralizingTableNameConvention)()

    'Specific Features of the MODEL Objects
    With modelBuilder.Entity(Of Model)()
        .Property(Function(t) t.model_id).
            HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasKey(Function(t) t.model_id)
        .Property(Function(t) t.Name).
            HasColumnName("ModelName")
    End With

    With modelBuilder.Entity(Of TableA)()
        .Property(Function(t) t.tablea_id).
            HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasKey(Function(t) t.tablea_id)
        .Property(Function(t) t.Name).
            HasColumnName("TableAName")

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of TableA)().
            HasMany(Function(t) t.TableBs).
            WithMany(Function(t) t.TableAs).
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.ToTable("TableA-TableB")
                m.MapLeftKey("tablea_id")
                m.MapRightKey("tableb-id")
            End Sub)
    End With

    With modelBuilder.Entity(Of TableB)()
        .Property(Function(t) t.tableb_id).
            HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasKey(Function(t) t.tableb_id)
        .Property(Function(t) t.Name).
            HasColumnName("TableBName")
    End With

End Class
```

Saving Routine that is called from the Main:

```
    Public Function PersistModel(CurrentModel As Model)
        Try
            Using context As New QDModelContext()
                Dim ModelObj As Model = New Model()
                context.Models.Add(ModelObj)
                context.SaveChanges()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            buildError("Couldn't Persist Model.", ex.Source & ": " & Err.Description, ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

I have tried defining the FK relationships properly and have encountered this following error:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of TableB)().
            HasRequired(Function(t) t.Model).
            WithMany(Function(t) t.TableBs).
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.MapKey("ModelID_FK")
            End Sub)
```

It works fine... but as soon as I add the many to many relationship it say it can't map some objects from TableA to Model.

so if I set this to Optional:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity(Of TableB)().
            HasOPTIONAL(Function(t) t.Model).
            WithMany(Function(t) t.TableBs).
        Map(Sub(m)
                m.MapKey("ModelID_FK")
            End Sub)
```

it works fine, it creates the Join table TableA-TableB but it adds a few row duplicates in table B with ModelID_FK null values... I think are those of the relationship TableA-TableB B values not existent in Table B.
Weird...

I wonder if it has to do with loading order or some cycle or order among the entities...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!!!